# How does Logstash tell out which line is new in log fie when the log source is a file?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

It is a SpringBoot website deployed in docker and ELK is used as log stack. The data source of Logstash is website.log.

I check the log from Kibana, and I see the log is based on the line as a unit.

Logstash is monitoring the website.log file and reading content from it as the data source.

While there are alreay many old lines in the file, I wonder when there is a new line coming into the website.log file, how Logstash can tell out which line is new and only send the new line to the ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logstash tracks the current position in file(s) it is configured to watch. See this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_tracking_of_current_position_in_watched_files) for more details on how logstash tracks current position in a file.

Answer (score 1):

While using the file plugin, you can set the start position to either beginning, or end which is described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-start_position). I think what you are looking at is the end configuration, where you want to only read the live stream of data that is coming to your logs.

Also, while matching the time, you can override the timestamp with the timestamp of the event, which is the timestamp that is recorded in the log, if it exists; with the [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) filter. That way, you can debug if it is reading the current lines or the older lines.